# Setting a href inside of template literals

Tags: javascript, express, nodemailer, template-literals

I'm trying to make use of a nice email template for when a user signs up with their email, I'm using express & node mailer to accomplish this. Previously my code looked like:

```
"Hello, " +
 user.username +
 ",\n\n" +
"Please complete your registration by clicking the link:
 \nhttp://" + req.headers.host + "/confirmation/" + user.username + "/" + token.token +
"\n\nThank you!\n"
```

Inside of my HTML template, which is a template literal ive tried this:

```
const output = ` <a href="${req.headers.host} + "/confirmation/" + ${user.username} + "/" + ${token.token}"  `
```

but this doesn't work, theres no `href` on the `<a>` inside of the email.

I must be missing something really basic... thanks for looking =)

Comment: you need to get rid of `+ "..." +` in between. Also both of these approaches are horribly susceptible to HTML injection vulnerabilities

Comment: Did you check what value `req.headers.host` contains?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ok thanks for pointing that out, what would be a better approach ?

Comment: @jfriend00 hi yes i did, it's either `localhost:3000` when im working locally or its my heroku app's url when deployed

Comment: @jroc you should probably use an environment variable for the hostname instead of reading it from the incoming request header, which could potentially be spoofed with any host.

Comment: Well starting a URL with `localhost:3000` does not make a valid URL.  You need a protocol like `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: @jfriend00 wow i'm dumb... thank you for pointing that out!!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ok that makes sense, ill set the variable inside of my heroku variables. thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `` you don't need to concatenate the string with `+`, so it should look like this:

```js
const output = `<a href="${req.headers.host}/confirmation/${user.username}/${token.token}"></a>`
```

Comment: In addition, a protocol is needed at the start of the URL.

Comment: thanks Verlin, your answer along with @jfriend00 's suggestion solved the issue.. thanks everyone!